# Good Shard Keys in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sharding

From the book Scaling MongoDB:

> **The general case**
>
> We can generalize this to a formula for shard keys:
>   {coarseLocality : 1, search : 1}

So my question is, is that correct? shouldn't be the oposite for better writing?

Also from the book:

> This pattern continues: everything will always be added to the “last”
>   chunk, meaning everything will be added to one shard. This shard key
>   gives you a single, undistributable hot spot.

So saying that my app always search by user_id, and last entries in the collection.

What is the best shard key i should have, this:

```
{_id:1, user_id:1}
```

or:

```
{user_id:1,_id:1}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kristina (author of *Scaling MongoDB*) wrote a blog post which has some example strategies explained in the guise of a game: [How to Choose a Shard Key: The Card Game](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2011/01/04/how-to-choose-a-shard-key-the-card-game/).

There are many considerations to [choosing a good shard key](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/) based on your application requirements and use cases.

The general advice of `{coarseLocality : 1, search : 1}` order is to ensure there is some locality of your data for reading.

So in your case, you would most likely want: `{user_id:1,_id:1}`.

That will provide some locality of data for the same `user_id` when querying, and ideally your common queries will be able to get their data from a single shard.

The opposite order may provide for better write distribution (assuming _id is not a monotonically increasing key like a default [ObjectId](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-The%5CidField)) but a potential downside is [reliability](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Choosing+a+Shard+Key#ChoosingaShardKey-Reliability): if your data for a read query is scattered across all shards, you will have retrieval problems if any one shard is down.

> So saying that my app always search by user_id, and last entries in the collection.

If you commonly search by `user_id` (and without `_id`) this will also affect your choice of shard key and [index optimization](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Choosing+a+Shard+Key#ChoosingaShardKey-Indexoptimization).  To find the last entries MongoDB will have to do a sort; you will want to be doing that sort on a single shard rather than having to gather the data from all shards and sorting.  If your `_id` happens to be date-based that would be beneficial as part of the shard key in order to find the last entries.

Comment: thanks.. i actually kind of realize this after 2-3 hours i posted this =) .. anyways my case i think i will have coarseLocality being "yyyy-mm" like the example in the book, because most of the time i search for multiple user_id in the same query, but I always search by last entries,so if I have coarseLocality being yyyy-mm i will likely search and order in one shard only.